# Using Scrapy to scrape MITOPENCOURSEWARE site for syllabi

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

My spider to scrape the MITOPENCOURSEWARE site for syllabi doesn't work. Will someone please help me figure out what's wrong with it? The .*'s are to get to all the courses. Is this right?

```
  1 from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
  2 from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
  3 from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
  4 from opensyllabi.items import OpensyllabiItem
  5 
  6 class MITSpider(CrawlSpider):
  7     name = 'mit'
  8     allowed_domains = ['ocw.mit.edu']
  9     start_urls = ['http://ocw.mit.edu/courses']
 10     rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=['/.*/.*/syllabus']), 'parse_syllabus')]
 11 
 12     def parse_syllabus(self, response):
 13         x = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
 14 
 15         syllabus = OpensyllabiItem()
 16         syllabus['url'] = response.url
 17         syllabus['body'] = x.select("//div[@id='course_inner_section']").extract()
 18         return syllabus
```

Comment: How do you know it is not working, i.e. what's happening?  And, be careful with `.*`, use sparingly. Try `'/[^/]+/[^/]+/syllabus'`.

Comment: It crawls 0 pages. Even if I do it your way.

Comment: Are there any links on your start urls with `syllabus`?  Show me link.

Comment: here's a link: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/architecture/4-196-architecture-design-level-ii-cuba-studio-spring-2004/syllabus/

Comment: My question actually is... is this link available from `http://ocw.mit.edu/courses`?  I don't see it.  In fact I don't see the word "syllabus" in the entire source.  The good news is, your spider is working :)

Comment: Oh, I see. Right, the link is not available there because the links are generated upon clicks. How do I crawl through that structure? I want to get the syllabi for every course under every department.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
rules = [
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'/[^/]+/[^/]+/syllabus'), 'parse_syllabus'),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor()),
]
```

to get all links on the first page, and then watch out, that's a lot of links.

Comment: Great! Worked. Thank you! Now, how do I save each one in a different file? I know how to put them all in one json file, but I'd like to separate them into different files.

Comment: Basically I just want the body text of each one saved into a file.

Comment: "Thank you" does not give our hard-working people here reputation. Up-voting and Accepting do.  Those are good things.  Then you can read the 500 pages on the net about how to solve your next issue after which you can certainly ask another question on SO.